# Let input number only accept number, comma and dot vue.js

Tags: javascript, linux, web, vuejs3

I am having an array of decimal data presented and optional to edit via web interface ie form.
My problem is that from Linux and Mac it works just fine but from Windows the input doesn't accept ',' comma in the input field

I'm looping through the array of arrays with a v-for loop of rows into the item holding the column for each row of input fields with values,

```
<input
         v-model="item.lab_data[8]"              
         title="Must contain a decimal number"
         type="number"
         class="form-control"
         required
         autofocus
    />
```

So my question is if there's any ideas why windows don't let me enter comma into the number field and how can I fix this?

My code is running on a Debian 11 client, vue 3, Nodejs 16

Answer (score 0):

The standard type of the number input field is integer. If you want to use [decimal values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values), you should add `step` to your input:

```
<input
     v-model="item.lab_data[8]"              
     title="Must contain a decimal number"
     type="number"
     step=“0.1”
     class="form-control"
     required
     autofocus
/>
```

The steps define the number of decimals you can use, so 0.1 is one decimal and 0.001 is three decimals etc.

Maybe on windows the browser validates during input, while on the other OS’es it validates on submit.

Comment: Don't forget about v-model modifiers. Using `.number` after the v-model will allow the value to be directly set as a number. See: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#number for extensive documentation !

Comment: @GeorgesA You don’t need the .number modifier explicitly if you use `type=“number”`. From the docs: “The number modifier is applied automatically if the input has type="number".”

Comment: Hi, have tested what you suggest, and it works for float like 0.1234 but not for 0,1234 input from windows.

One of my conclusions is that Windows parse on keypress event and rest parse and replace on onleave event. Can that be true??

That is as you Gabe indicates

Comment: @Gabe, tested step="0.0001" but no luck there, can't still write ',' -char like 0,0001
Think this is an US numbering thing...

Comment: @AndersS Yes, maybe your browser language is set to English on windows? On in Chrome on Mac it does not matter, you can use a dot and a comma as a separator, but maybe on windows there is a more restrictive validation.